# JSF passing a bean to a page

Tags: jsf

I have created a little controller of sorts that depending on the input could send it to a number of pages each with a different backing bean.  I do this because one page, which takes a case number, verifies that case number and then passes it on to any number of pages which need a valid case number.

Here is my caseSelector page:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText value="#{caseSelectorBean.caseNumber}"/> 
    <h:inputHidden value="#{caseSelectorBean.nextPage}"/> 
    <h:commandButton action="#{caseSelectorBean.gotoNext}" value="submit"/> 
</h:form>
```

my bean correctly verifies the casenumber and fills out the bean for the next page and forwards it to that page.

```
//CaseSelectorBean
public String gotoNext()  {
    logger.debug("In the caseChooser, going to xpage");
    logger.debug("caseNum=" + caseNumber);

    if(!validateCaseNumber(caseNumber)) {
        return "caseNotFound";
    }   

    if(nextPage.equals("page1")) {
        CaseDAO caseDAO = new CaseDAO();
        caseInfo = caseDAO.getCaseInfo(caseNumber);
        CaseInfoBean caseInfoBean = new CaseInfoBean();
        caseInfoBean.setCaseInfo(caseInfo);
        caseInfoBean.setCaseNumber(caseNumber);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(
                    "caseInfoBean", caseInfoBean);

    }

    logger.debug("done with gotoNext(), returning " + nextPage);
    return nextPage;
}
```

problem is when I try to access the bean from the next page, it's empty.  I can see via the constructor, it created a new one instead of using the one in the session.  How would I make the page use the bean I created for it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the scope of your bean. It should be SessionScoped.

Comment: I did have it request.  When I change it to session, I got 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean caseSelectorBean.  The following problems were found:
     - The scope of the object referenced by expression #{param.caseNumber}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (caseSelectorBean) scope of session  

because I have a managed property, 
 <managed-property>
            <property-name>caseNumber</property-name>
            <value>#{param.caseNumber}</value>
        </managed-property>

Comment: Is there a better way to pass the caseNumber parameter from a jsp page?

Comment: See this link - http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/, I think all of them are better then hidden field. Just one note, if you are running on Tomcat 7 or Glassfish, then you can pass parameter to method without including `el-impl-2.2.jar`

Answer (score 0):

The ManagedProperty with `#{param}` works only for request scoped beans. Use `f:viewParam` for broader scopes:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="caseNumber" value="#{caseSelectorBean.caseNumber}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Then you need only a simple property caseNumber with getter and setter in your bean.